# How to change button's color individually in a group of button from another bigger group of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change button color individually when i click.

Requirement:

1. Buttons default color: grey, First Click: Green, Second Click: Red, Third click: go back grey.
2. The button is in a group of button from another bigger group of color.

I'm stuck in JS. I'm not sure how to make the button color change (grey, red and green).

Please help.

```js
var SafetybtnColor = document.getElementsByClassName('Safetybtn');
var Safetybtns = document.querySelectorAll('button.Safetybtn');
SafetybtnColor.onclick = function() {
 
}
```

```html
<h>Group 1</h>
<div style="position:relative; top:5px" class=Safetybtn>
          <button id="s1">1</button>
          <button id="s2">2</button>
          <button id="s3">3</button>
          <button id="s4">4</button>
          <button id="s5">5</button>
</div>
<br>
<h> Group 2</h>
<div style="position:relative; top:5px" class=QualityIntbtn>
          <button id="qi1">1</button>
          <button id="qi2">2</button>
          <button id="qi3">3</button>
          <button id="qi4">4</button>
          <button id="qi5">5</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to create an array of colors to traverse through, and assign the onclick of each button to a function to twiddle the color.

i tweaked your html a bit to add a class to make it easy to identify which buttons should have this functionality. also added a data-* attribute to hold the current 'color' value for each button. this is each buttons state.

```
<h>Group 1</h>
<div style="position:relative; top:5px" class=Safetybtn>
          <button id="s1" class="colorable" data-color="0">1</button>
          <button id="s2" class="colorable" data-color="0">2</button>
          <button id="s3" class="colorable" data-color="0">3</button>
          <button id="s4" class="colorable" data-color="0">4</button>
          <button id="s5" class="colorable" data-color="0">5</button>
</div>
<br>
<h> Group 2</h>
<div style="position:relative; top:5px" class=QualityIntbtn>
          <button id="qi1" class="colorable" data-color="0">1</button>
          <button id="qi2" class="colorable" data-color="0">2</button>
          <button id="qi3" class="colorable" data-color="0">3</button>
          <button id="qi4" class="colorable" data-color="0">4</button>
          <button id="qi5" class="colorable" data-color="0">5</button>
</div>
```

the javascript is fairly straightforward

```
var colors = [
    "lightgray", "green", "red"
];

var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("colorable");
for (idx = 0; idx < btns.length; idx++) {
    var btn = btns[idx];

    btn.onclick = function() {
        var colorIndex = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-color")) + 1

        if (colorIndex > 2) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }

        this.setAttribute("data-color", colorIndex);
        this.style.background = colors[colorIndex];
    }
}
```

the colors array could be rgb values or whatever. i used names for simplicity.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ns56c34u/

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you need to put quotation marks around your class names. Also, note that `button.Safetybtn` is not a valid selector, as your buttons don't have the class *themselves*. You're looking for `.Safetybtn button`, because the buttons are a *child* or the `Safetybtn` class. You could also use the **[child combinator `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** to denote a *direct* child, with `.Safetybtn > button`.

Now that you have the group of buttons, you'll want to loop over them with a simple `for` loop. Within that loop, simply set the `onclick` for each `Safetybtns[i]`, wherein you can change the colour with the **[`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)**, using `this.style.backgroundColor`.

Note that the actual background 'grey' for buttons is a rather specific colour: `rgb(221, 221, 221)`.

You'll want an index (in my example `selectColour`) that gets increased each time you click on the buttons. You'll also want to set it back to zero once it's one less than the number of colours you're looping over (to reset the loop).

I'm not sure of your **exact** requirements, but here's an example that stores the three colours `red`, `green` and `grey` as an array, and swaps between them whenever **any** button is clicked:

```js
var Safetybtns = document.querySelectorAll('.Safetybtn button');

var colours = ['green', 'red', 'rgb(221, 221, 221)'];
var selectedColour = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < Safetybtns.length; i++) {
  Safetybtns[i].onclick = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = colours[selectedColour];
    if (selectedColour != colours.length - 1) {
      selectedColour++;
    }
    else {
      selectedColour = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h>Group 1</h>
<div style="position:relative; top:5px" class="Safetybtn">
  <button id="s1">1</button>
  <button id="s2">2</button>
  <button id="s3">3</button>
  <button id="s4">4</button>
  <button id="s5">5</button>
</div>
<br>
<h> Group 2</h>
<div style="position:relative; top:5px" class="QualityIntbtn">
  <button id="qi1">1</button>
  <button id="qi2">2</button>
  <button id="qi3">3</button>
  <button id="qi4">4</button>
  <button id="qi5">5</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to keep a click `counter` for each button so as to change to a specific color each time.

You can add a custom attribute to each button like `data-clikcs="0"` to use as a counter, but I'll just use the button's `title` for storage because it's easier:

```
<button id="s1" onclick="this.title=Number(this.title)+1; CycleColor(this.id,this.title)" title="0">1</button>

<button id="s2" onclick="this.title=Number(this.title)+1; CycleColor(this.id,this.title)" title="0">2</button>

<button id="s3" onclick="this.title=Number(this.title)+1; CycleColor(this.id,this.title)" title="0">3</button>
```

And we'll need a function that each button will call to have its colors changed...

```
function CycleColor(Which, ClickNum){
    var B=document.getElementById(Which);

    if(ClickNum=='1'){B.style.background='green';} 
    else if(ClickNum=='2'){B.style.background='red';} 
    else {B.style.background='grey';} 
}
```